# How to avoid syncing time with NTP when offset is more than 1000 sec on running system?

Tags: ntp

We support configuring NTP for time sync in my application.But my webapps are sensitive to sudden time changes. So we wanted to allow time sync with ntp only if the offset is less than 1000sec on running system and allow large values during boot. How to achieve this? I tried by removing "tinker panic 0" from ntp.conf file. But still it is syncing large values without any reboot.
And also seeing different behaviour on different environment.

1. Normal hardware server - Syncs even if the time difference is more than 1000 sec
2. ESX VM - Doesn't sync
3. KVN VM - Syncs even if the time difference is more than 1000 sec
4. Hyper-V VM - Syncs even if the time difference is more than 1000 sec

All these servers are running on Centos 6.7

Do we have any configuration options to achieve this?

Following is my ntp.conf content.

```
leapfile "/etc/ntp/leap-seconds.list"

restrict default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict -6 ::1

tos orphan 10
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift
keys /etc/ntp/keys

server  127.127.1.0      # local clock
server x.x.x.x
```

Comment: Are you quite sure it's `ntpd` that's skewing the time in a jump?  That would be unusual for it, to say the least.  If on the other hand you don't want `ntpdate` to jump the clock, don't run it.

Comment: Yes. We are seeing logs in /var/log/message like below."Jan 28 10:10:19 hostname ntpd[43297]: 0.0.0.0 061c 0c clock_step 201695.631881 s". we wanted to allow time sync if the difference is less than 1000 sec. we are not running ntpdate command while configuring ntp server entry in ntp.conf file.

Comment: Fair enough.  Are you running `ntpd` with the `-g` flag?

Comment: We have tried with -g option also. Still it is syncing even if the offset is huge.

Comment: Is it syncing with huge offset **without** `-g`?  Is that the whole of your `ntp.conf` file?  Have you tried without the `server 127.127.1.0` line?  Could we see the output of `ntptrace`?

Comment: We found some info on this. Actually by default ntpd is starting with -g option. Due to this by default it is syncing even if the offset is more.   CentOs is by default specifying -g option. Is there any way to override these options without modifying ntpd file?[root@ci-9cb654974f88 ~]# rpm -q --whatprovides /etc/sysconfig/ntpd
ntp-4.2.6p5-5.el6.centos.x86_64
[root@ci-9cb654974f88 ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/ntpd
# Drop root to id 'ntp:ntp' by default.
OPTIONS="-u ntp:ntp -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g"

Comment: How about taking `-g` out of the `OPTIONS` line?

Comment: Why oh why are you syncing to local clock? There is almost  never a good reason to have  `127.127.1.0`  in your config file if you are connected to the internet.